# Kivy: How to automate clock processes one after the other

Tags: python, kivy

Was writing a tetris game and have come across some challenges which seem insurmountable. I would like the blocks to fall one after the other systematically but can't seem to get it as i come across one error after the other. This is my the error serving code

```
#All modules have been imported
class block1(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(block1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        xpositions = (0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400)
        self.bind(pos= self.fall)
        self.pos_x = random.choice(xpositions)
        self.pos_y = Window.height
        self.pos = (self.pos_x,self.pos_y)
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = -5
        velocity = vel_x,vel_y

    def fall(self, **kwargs):
        self.pos =  Vector(*self.position) + self.pos
        if self.pos[1]==0:
            self.position[1] = 0
            return self.pos

    @classmethod
    def new_widget(cls):
        return cls
        #This widget is intended to help me create the new instance of a the 
same class i.e to multiply this block within my app
class block2(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(block1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        xpositions = (0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400)
        self.bind(pos= self.fall)
        self.pos_x = random.choice(xpositions)
        self.pos_y = Window.height
        self.pos = (self.pos_x,self.pos_y)
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = -5
        velocity = vel_x,vel_y

    def fall(self, **kwargs):
        self.pos =  Vector(*self.position) + self.pos
        if self.pos[1]==0:
            self.position[1] = 0
            return self.pos
    @classmethod
    def new_widget(cls):
        return cls
    #This widget is intended to help me create the new instance of a the 
same class i.e to multiply this block within my app
```

I am facing three problems. The first is from my function under my block class call `fall` I keep getting an error that says `block1 has no attribute called velocity` when it is clearly  in my `__init__` function.

I defined two new block classes customized the `.kv` files for each, defining different colors and sizes for each. I made my code to define a new startup position and a fixed velocity whenever the class was created. After this I then created the fall class to make my application fall.
In the build of my app class i tried to make the blocks fall one after the other by detecting when one has fallen and making the next begin then.

```
def build(self):
    game= board()
    first = block1()
    second = block2()
    game.add_widget(first)
    Clock.schedule_interval(first.fall, 1/60)
    if first.pos[1] == 0:
        game.add_widget(second)
        Clock.schedule_interval(second.fall, 1/60)
```

Secondly in my **init** function i tried to bind the `fall` function to the `pos` property of the class so as the block falls, the `pos` property of the class changes with it. Regardless the program doesn't seem to detect the change in the `pos` regardless of the bind.

Lastly I tried to create a new `@classmethod` that would help me create new blocks repeatedly and infinitely for the tetris app and dont know where i got it wrong. I created a class method that returns a new instance of the class and planned on creating a loop that keeps creating a new instance of a class in this way:

```
game = tetrisgame()#This is the main layout for the game
while game:#To create a loop to keep adding new blocks
        blockchoice = randint(1,6)
        if blockchoice == 1:
            game.add_widget(block1.new_widget)
            Clock.schedule_interval(block1.fall,1/60)
            for i in allblocks:
                if block1.collide_widget(i):
                    block1.position[1] = 0
```

This gives me a bind error saying `widget.bind` error, and fails to create a new instance for my class.
Could someone help me clarify?
Note: I tried to pick out the parts of the code that were the source of the error to prevent having a post with a lengthy amount of code, so please note that all modules have been imported and the `.kv` files with all the designs are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here. Your `block1` indeed does not have a `velocity` attribute. The `velocity` mentioned in your `__init__()` is only a local variable. If you want it to be an attribute, you must assign it as `self.velocity=`. Also the reference to `velx,vely` does not reference the attributes `self.velx` and `self.vely`.

Your `fall()` method references a `self.position` that I do not see defined anywhere.

I don't see how your widget position is being changed. Perhaps that line in your `fall()` method should be: `self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos`.

The `pos` attribute of the `Widget` tells `Kivy` where to draw it, so I don't think you worry about binding `pos` to anything, it will be the position of the `Widget`.